# Openshift-django-mysql : No tables created to database via syncdb

Tags: python, mysql, django, openshift

My settings.py

```
if ON_OPENSHIFT:
     DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'django',
            'USER': 'USER',
            'PASSWORD': 'PASS',
            'HOST': '127.2.202.129',
            'PORT': '3306',
        }
    }
```

and my action_hooks/deploy

```
source $OPENSHIFT_APP_DIR/virtenv/bin/activate
export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=$OPENSHIFT_APP_DIR/virtenv/lib/python-2.6

echo "Executing 'python $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/my/manage.py syncdb --noinput'"
python $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/my/manage.py syncdb --noinput

echo "Executing 'python $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/my/manage.py collectstatic --noinput'"
python $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/my/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

and whenever i do,

```
git add .
git commit -a -m "project"
git push
```

my database shows no tables...why??
THANKS iin advance

Comment: Are you getting errors in the output of git push? Another thing would be to try running those commands directly on the application gear.

Comment: can u direct, where @ application gear

Answer (score 1):

Read this and you will understand a lot more about Django on OpenShift

http://appsembler.com/blog/django-deployment-using-openshift/

Comment: sir, i have tried that, but I think my deploy script is not running while git push, How to know is that running or not

Comment: Did you git add it?

``git add -a .